Singleton array array(<surprise.dataset.DatasetAutoFolds object at 'address'>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection
I'm trying to use GridsearchCV and fit() on a 'surprise.dataset.DatasetAutoFolds' but it kept returning this error. Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from surprise import Reader, Dataset, SVD
import time
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

#...data preprocessing...
data = Dataset.load_from_df(movielens[['userId', 'movieId', 'rating']], Reader())

sim_options2 = {
    "n_factors": [50,100],
    "n_epochs": [10,20],
    "lr_all": [0.05],
}

param_grid = {"sim_options": sim_options}

gs = GridSearchCV(SVD, sim_options2,
                   scoring=['neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_absolute_error'], cv=KFold(5, shuffle=False), 
                   n_jobs=6, refit=False)
gs.fit(data)

error below :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 18
     14 gs = GridSearchCV(SVD, sim_options2,
     15                    scoring=['neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_absolute_error'], cv=KFold(5, shuffle=False), 
     16                    n_jobs=6, refit=False)
     17 #gs.fit(data)
---> 18 gs.fit(data)
     19 gs.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
     20 print(gs.best_score["rmse"])

File c:\Users\miniconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1473, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1466     estimator._validate_params()
   1468 with config_context(
   1469     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1470         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1471     )
   1472 ):
-> 1473     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\miniconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:872, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, **params)
    869 estimator = self.estimator
    870 scorers, refit_metric = self._get_scorers()
--> 872 X, y = indexable(X, y)
    873 params = _check_method_params(X, params=params)
...
    389     # Dask dataframes may not return numeric shape[0] value
    390     if isinstance(x.shape[0], numbers.Integral):

TypeError: Singleton array array(<surprise.dataset.DatasetAutoFolds object at 0x000001DCA85A1760>,
      dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection

Yesterday I was still able to fit the data and get best parameters out of it so I assume that the problem is not the dataset. But after some changes the code now shows this error. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.
